# Is there a better way to write this code rather than using all these if loops?

Tags: c++, integer

The goal of this program is to be able to translate intergers in the range 0 to 9999 into an English description of the number.

While my program is able to accomplish this. I want to make without all these if loops or at least minimize them. Any tips/help is greatly apprecitaed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int numberEntered, digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour;


    string lessThan20[] = { "zero" , "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", 
                            "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty"};
    string tens[] = {"twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
    string hundred = "hundred";
    string thousand = "thousand";

    cout << "Enter A Number: " << endl;
    cin >> numberEntered;

    if (numberEntered <= 20) {
        
        cout << " You entered " << lessThan20[numberEntered] << endl;

    }

    if (numberEntered > 20 && numberEntered <= 99) {
    
    
        digitOne = numberEntered / 10;
        digitTwo = numberEntered -= digitOne * 10;

        if (digitTwo == 0) {
            
            cout << "You entered " << tens[digitOne - 2] << endl;
            
        }
        else {
        
            cout << "You entered " << tens[digitOne - 2] << " " << lessThan20[digitTwo] << endl;
        }

    }


    if (numberEntered > 99 && numberEntered <= 999) {
    
    
        digitOne = numberEntered / 100;
        numberEntered = numberEntered - (digitOne * 100);

        digitTwo = numberEntered / 10;

        digitThree = numberEntered % 10;

        if (digitTwo == 0 && digitThree > 0) {
        
            cout << "You entered " << lessThan20[digitOne] << " hundred " << lessThan20[digitThree];

        }

        if (digitThree == 0 && digitTwo > 0) {
            
            cout << "You entered " << lessThan20[digitOne] << " hundred " << tens[digitTwo] << endl;

        
        }

        if (digitTwo == 0 && digitThree == 0) {
        
            cout << "You entered " << lessThan20[digitOne] << " " << hundred << endl;
            
        }
        
        if (digitOne > 1 && digitTwo > 1 && digitThree > 1) {
        
            cout << "You entered " << lessThan20[digitOne] << " " << hundred << " " << tens[digitTwo - 2] << " " << lessThan20[digitThree] << endl;
     

        }
        
        
    }


    if (numberEntered > 999 && numberEntered <= 9999) {
    
        digitOne = numberEntered / 1000;
        numberEntered = numberEntered - (1000 * digitOne);

        digitTwo = numberEntered / 100;
        numberEntered = numberEntered - (100 * digitTwo);

        digitThree = numberEntered / 10;

        digitFour = numberEntered % 10;

        if (digitOne > 0 && digitTwo > 0 && digitThree > 0 && digitFour >> 0) {
        
        
            cout << "You entered " << lessThan20[digitOne] << " " << thousand << " " << lessThan20[digitTwo] << " " << hundred << " " << tens[digitThree - 2] << " " << lessThan20[digitFour] << endl;
       
        }


        if ( digitTwo == 0 && digitThree > 0 && digitFour > 0) {
        
            cout << "You entered " << lessThan20[digitOne] << " " << thousand << " " << tens[digitThree - 2] << " " << lessThan20[digitFour] << endl;


        }

        if (digitTwo == 0 && digitThree == 0 && digitFour > 0) {

            cout << "You entered " << lessThan20[digitOne] << " " << thousand << " " << lessThan20[digitFour] << endl;


        }

        if (digitTwo == 0 && digitThree == 0 && digitFour == 0) {

            cout << "You entered " << lessThan20[digitOne] << " " << thousand << endl;


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _"if loop"_?? What's that, elaborate please!! There's no _loop_ statement in your example codes at all.

Comment: Of course there is a trivial, easy way. For example, step 1: if the number is 1000 or more, print the number of thousands, subtract them from the number, then keep going. Now you only need to concern yourself with the rest of the numbers less than a 1000, and write the code for that. See how simple this is? Repeat with 100, and so on. The only exception case you will need to deal separately with is the number 0.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `if (number <= 20) ... if (number > 20 && number <= 99) ...` tests against 20 twice. You can eliminate that duplication (hence, reduce the chance for errors creeping in during maintenance) with `if (number <= 20) ... else if (number <= 99) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid the `if`s, because you must make some decisions.

You could hide a lot of things in a `std::map` or `std__unordered_map`.

However, you could optimize the code by using a kind of recursion, where you reuse your own function for parts of the original number.

Something like the below.

But there are millions of potential solutions. Here is one of them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <array>

constexpr std::array<std::string_view,10> t0_9{ "","one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
constexpr std::array<std::string_view,10> t10_19{ "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen","sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
constexpr std::array<std::string_view,10> T20_90{ "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

std::string convert(unsigned long number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        return std::string(t0_9[number]);
    }
    else if (number < 20) {
        return std::string(t10_19[number - 10]);
    }
    else if (number < 100) {
        return std::string(T20_90[number / 10]) + ((number % 10 != 0) ? " " + convert(number % 10) : "");
    }
    else if (number < 1000) {
        return convert(number / 100) + " hundred" + ((number % 100 != 0) ? " " + convert(number % 100) : "");
    }
    else if (number < 1000000) {
        return convert(number / 1000) + " thousand" + ((number % 1000 != 0) ? " " + convert(number % 1000) : "");
    }
    else if (number < 1000000000) {
        return convert(number / 1000000) + " million" + ((number % 1000000 != 0) ? " " + convert(number % 1000000) : "");
    }
    else if (number < 1000000000000) {
        return convert(number / 1000000000) + " billion" + ((number % 1000000000 != 0) ? " " + convert(number % 1000000000) : "");
    }
    return "error";
}
int main() {
    std::cout << '\n' << convert(12345) << '\n';
}
```